# how to organise a list of messages by last sent

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm struggling finding a proper way of retrieving proper results from my mysql table.
I have a table used to store messages:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `who` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

This table stores all the messages from all the conversations between all the members.
To organize the results, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages group by who order by date desc
```

It groups properly the messages according their senders, but it orders it according the date of the first message written by a certain member. I want to make it to order the output according the date of the last message. 
Please help me find a way out of this, I have a feeling it has to be simple, but I still can't see a way. Ready to give more explanations if needed.
Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with a `SELECT *` when using `GROUP BY`, this will take the last date as a basis for the order:

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY who ORDER BY MAX(date) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to order it by the date of the last sent, then simply change the query to:

`SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC`

That will simply ordered it most recent first, oldest last

Comment: Rodin's answer is great if you're simply wanting the last reply and grouping with `who`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just
Select * from messages order by who asc, date desc
?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

SELECT distinct m.who, m.* FROM messages m order by date desc